# Fluentd unable to connect to AWS elasticsearch service using fluent-plugin-elasticsearch

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, fluentd, amazon-ami, aws-elasticsearch

We are using AWS Elasticsearch Service and fleuntd to push the logs of microservice. We have installed fluentd on EC2 instance using docker based configuration. We have followed the steps mentioned in the https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/docker-compose and also it was working pretty fine till last week. There is no change in the configuration of both elastcicsearch service and ec2 instance we are provisioning. Below is the error logs we are getting.

> 2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 unexpected error
> error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method
> `host_unreachable_exceptions' for #<Elasticsearch::Transport::Client:0x00007fe5231b5e08>"   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-5.0.5/lib/fluent/plugin/elasticsearch_index_template.rb:41:in` rescue in retry_operate'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-5.0.5/lib/fluent/plugin/elasticsearch_index_template.rb:39:in
> `retry_operate'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-5.0.5/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:487:in` handle_last_seen_es_major_version'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000
> [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-5.0.5/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:339:in
> `configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/plugin.rb:178:in` configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/agent.rb:132:in
> `add_match'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/agent.rb:74:in` block in configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/agent.rb:64:in
> `each'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/agent.rb:64:in` configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:146:in
> `configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/engine.rb:105:in` configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/engine.rb:80:in
> `run_configure'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:714:in` block in run_worker'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:966:in
> `main_process'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:706:in` run_worker'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:364:in
> `<top (required)>'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in` require'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in
> `require'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.13.3/bin/fluentd:15:in` <top
> (required)>'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0
> /usr/bin/fluentd:23:in `load'   2021-08-05 20:35:57 +0000 [error]: #0 /usr/bin/fluentd:23:in` '

Below is the configuration used.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    ports:
      - "8880:8880"
      - "8880:8880/udp"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.13.3
USER root
RUN ["gem", "install", "fluent-plugin-elasticsearch", "--no-document", "--version", "5.0.5"]
USER fluent
```

**fluentd.conf**

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 8880
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match **>
    host ES_HOT
    port 443
    scheme https
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix "fluentd-logs"
    logstash_dateformat "%Y%m%d"
    user "elastic"
    password xxxxxx
    flush_interval 10s
    fail_on_detecting_es_version_retry_exceed false
    verify_es_version_at_startup false
    max_retry_get_es_version 2
    default_elasticsearch_version 7.10
    request_timeout 60s
    reload_on_failure true
</match>
```

Our configuration with **AWS Elasticsearch Service 7.10**, **Fluentd v1.12.0-debian-1.0** and **fluent-plugin-elasticsearch 4.3.3**, was working perfectly fine till last week. One of the ec2 instance which was provisioned 10 days back, was able to connect and push the logs as well. But when we restarted that instance its also stopped working with the same error. We have Terraform scripts that provision all infrastructure. Later, we have tried different versions combinations as well. But nothing worked out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying to setup fluentd against Open Distro for Elasticsearch and I'm getting a similar error. As I understand, Amazon Elasticsearch Service uses Open Distro, so this likely has the same root cause. I tested against the equivalent Elasticsearch proper version (7.10.2) and it was able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Digging into the matter, I found that the `fluent-plugin-elasticsearch` plugin doesn't version-lock its dependencies, including `elasticsearch-transport` and `elasticsearch-api`, and that a recent update somewhere in one of those led to some kind of incompatibility.

The fix that worked for me was to explicitly install the dependencies at the latest issue-free version to avoid having the `fluent-plugin-elasticsearch` install pull the latest issue-causing version.

### Proposed Modification to your Dockerfile

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.13.3
USER root
RUN ["gem", "install", "elasticsearch", "--no-document", "--version", "7.13.3"]
RUN ["gem", "install", "fluent-plugin-elasticsearch", "--no-document", "--version", "5.0.5"]
USER fluent
```

Answer (score 0):

I launched an AWS Elasticsearch 7.10 managed service cluster and connected an EKS cluster to it with this Fluentd docker image:

**fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.12.0-debian-elasticsearch7-1.0**

Deploy manifest:

```
piVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging # This label will help group your daemonset pods
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule # This will ensure fluentd collects master logs too
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.12.0-debian-elasticsearch7-1.0
          env:
            - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: {{ .Values.elasticSearch.loggingHost | quote }}
            - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: {{ .Values.elasticSearch.port | quote }}
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
              value: {{ .Values.elasticSearch.scheme | quote }}
            #- name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
            #  value: "elastic"
            #- name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
            #  value: ""
            - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
            - name: config-volume-fluentd
              mountPath: /fluentd/etc/conf.d/

      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume-fluentd
          configMap:
            name: config-volume-fluentd
            defaultMode: 0777

        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: fluentd
    namespace: kube-system
```

Config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-volume-fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: fluentd
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
#    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
data:
  fluentd.conf: |-

    <filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.app-resolver-**>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      reserve_data true
      remove_key_name_field false
      hash_value_field json_log
      emit_invalid_record_to_error false
      <parse>
        @type json
      </parse>
    </filter>

    <filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.scan-app-**>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      reserve_data true
      remove_key_name_field false
      hash_value_field json_log
      emit_invalid_record_to_error false
      <parse>
        @type json
      </parse>
    </filter>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.app-resolver-**>
      @type elasticsearch
      host {{ .Values.elasticSearch.loggingHost }}
      port {{ .Values.elasticSearch.port }}
      scheme {{ .Values.elasticSearch.scheme }}
      log_es_400_reason true
      logstash_format true
      logstash_dateformat {{ .Values.elasticSearch.dateFormat }}
      logstash_prefix k8s-sqs-services
    </match>

    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.scan-app-**>
      @type elasticsearch
      host {{ .Values.elasticSearch.loggingHost }}
      port {{ .Values.elasticSearch.port }}
      scheme {{ .Values.elasticSearch.scheme }}
      log_es_400_reason true
      logstash_format true
      logstash_dateformat {{ .Values.elasticSearch.dateFormat }}
      logstash_prefix k8s-sqs-services
    </match>

  containers.input.conf: |-
    <match raw.kubernetes.**>
      @id raw.kubernetes
      @type detect_exceptions
      remove_tag_prefix raw
      message log
      stream stream
      multiline_flush_interval 5
      max_bytes 500000
      max_lines 1000
    </match>
  system.conf: |-
    <system>
      root_dir /tmp/fluentd-buffers/
    </system>
  system.input.conf: |-

    <source>
      @id cluster-autoscaler.log
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(? 
    <source>
      [^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/cluster-autoscaler.log
      pos_file /var/log/cluster-autoscaler.log.pos
      tag cluster-autoscaler
    </source>
```